# Can't iterate over a python dictionary

Tags: python, arguments, attributeerror

I try to pass a dictionnary to a function that will "parse" it but I can't iterate over it, It looks simple but can't understand what's happening.

My function:

```
    def _build_options(self, options):
        print options
        for option, value in options.iteritems():
            if option not in self._optionslist:
                del options[option]
        return options
```

options:

```
 {'segment_container': None, 'use_slo': False, 'log_level': 'INFO', 
'dir_marker': 'False', 'changed': None, 'leave_segments': False, 'fail_fast':
 False, 'headers': 'X-Delete-After:50, X-Upload:None', 'meta': [], 
'ttl': None, 'segment_size': None, 'skip_identical': False}
```

My code raises this:

```
AttributeError: Values instance has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Thanks

edit:
type(options):

```
 <type 'instance'>
```

dir(options):

```
['__cmp__', '__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', '__repr__', '__str__',
 '_update', '_update_careful', '_update_loose', 'changed', 'dir_marker',
'ensure_value', 'fail_fast', 'headers', 'leave_segments', 'log_level', 'meta', 'read_file', 'read_module', 
'segment_container', 'segment_size', 'skip_identical', 'ttl', 'use_slo']
```

I tried options = dict(options) but I get the error:

```
    TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
```

Edit2:
I have a method upload() in which I call _build_options():

```
def upload(self, paths, ttl, options):
     # [...]
     # print options, type(options)
     # the dictionnary is well printed but its type is "instance"
     opts = self._build_options(options)
```

upload() is called in an other file like this:

```
self.swift_mng.upload(filename, None, options)
```

and I get options from optparse.parse_args()

Comment: you have  a Value instance not a dict, what is Value?

Comment: Also check `dir(options)` to see the methods available

Comment: Also should you not be using self.options, I presume it is an attribute of the class?

Comment: If you're using Python 3, `iteritems` has been deprecated in favour of `items` - but like @PadraicCunningham says, it doesn't appear to be a dictionary - one to bear in mind, however

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are not using a dictionary, it just looks like that when you print it (it is the `__str__` method in the class making it look like that).

Read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html) for `optparse`, and also [this](http://pymotw.com/2/optparse/).

`options` is an object containing values for your options.  So far as I can tell, you cannot iterate over the options (there is no `__iter__`, for example, in the class), you can only test the individual option values.

EDIT: However, I did find this that might be useful:  http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/344094/

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the Attribute error. But you **can not** change the dictionary size when you are looping over it. As mentioned in comments you can check for type of options, and do some thing like this:

```
def _build_options(self, options):
    if type(options) == dict:
        for option in self._optionslist:
            if option in options:
                del options[option]
        return options
```

Comment: isinstance is the correct way to check , has_key should not be used and does not exist in python3  and this also does not answer the question.

Comment: It works well now thanks you !! But I don't understand why this fixed my problem. Edit: in fact it doesn't

Comment: can you also post the calling part. I mean where you call this method. There has to be some problem there since this part seems fine.

Comment: I think you are directly passing the options received from    'optparse.parse_args()'. Can you confirm this that whether you are doing like this or not. 'options = parser.parse_args()' and then 'self.swift_mng.upload(filename, None, options)'